# SQLite3 + Python3 - creating a database with foreign keys

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.x, foreign-keys

Hi there everyone,

I'm having a little trouble with sqlite3 and python3. I think I'm having one of those dumb moments again, but I'm trying to essentially trying to make the table below.

The sticking point seems to be the foreign keys - I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't quite worked out what - and my google searches aren't really getting me anywhere. I can't find any good documentation. I've tried multiple different syntax's for foreign key's online, but none are getting me any nearer to a working table.

[image: Database relational view]

```
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE Driver (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT,
          FirstName text,
          LastName text,
          RegistrationNo text)
          ''')

c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE Passenger (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT,
          FirstName text,
          LastName text)
          ''')

c.execute('''
          pragma foreign_keys=on;
          begin transaction;

          CREATE TABLE Journey (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT,
          Driver_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
          FOREIGN KEY (Driver_ID) REFERENCES Driver,
          Origin text,
          Destination text,
          SeatsAvailable integer,
          Date text,
          Time text,
          DriverNotes text,
          PassengerNotes text)
          ''')

c.execute('''
          pragma foreign_keys=on;
          begin transaction;

          CREATE TABLE Assigned Passengers (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT,
          Journey_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
          FOREIGN KEY (Journey_ID) REFERENCES Journey,
          Passenger_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
          FOREIGN KEY (Passenger_ID) REFERENCES Passenger
          ''')
```

One of the messages I'm getting is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Computer/Bitbucket/Python Project/sql.py", line 46, in <module>
    ''')
sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.
```

Line 46 is at the end of the Journey creation block.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As the message tells you, you can only execute one statement at a time.
2. You need to execute `PRAGMA foreign_keys` only once for the connection.
3. Executing `BEGIN TRANSACTIOn` makes no sense here.
4. A PRIMARY KEY constraint already implies NOT NULL.
5. A PRIMARY KEY constraint already implies UNIQUE.
6. If a table name contains a space, you must quote it.
7. When you declare a foreign key as a table constraint, you must write it after all the columns, and must not forget the delimiting comma.
8. When you declare a foreign key as a column constraint, you must use the correct syntax:

```
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE Journey (
              ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
              Driver_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Driver(ID),
              Origin text,
              Destination text,
              SeatsAvailable integer,
              Date text,
              Time text,
              DriverNotes text,
              PassengerNotes text)
          ''')
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE Assigned_Passengers (
              ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
              Journey_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Journey(ID),
              Passenger_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Passenger(ID))
          ''')
```

Comment: Thank you for all of that - you've been a great help! :) Have a nice day!